# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property X of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I have following Interface to be used as a type for a JSON file :

```html
export interface IIndustrySectors {
  IndustrySector: string;
  isSelected: string;
  dataSubjectCategories:string[];
  dataTypeCategories:string[];
  SubIndustries:[{
    IndustrySector: string;
    isSelected: string;
    dataSubjectCategories:string[];
    dataTypeCategories:string[];
    SubIndustries:[{}]
  }]
}
```

and, two services:

```js
 
 
 // Read all the Data from the JSON file
 getMainIndustrySectors(): Observable<IIndustrySectors[]> {
    return this.http.get<IIndustrySectors[]>(this.industrySectorsURL).pipe(
      tap(((data) => console.log('All: ' + data) )),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

//Get Specific object 
  getBySector(sector): Observable<IIndustrySectors|  undefined> {
    return this.getMainIndustrySectors().pipe(
      map((products: IIndustrySectors[]) => products.find(p => p.IndustrySector === sector)));

  }
```

Here is a part of the JSON file

```html
 [
   {
      "IndustrySector":"Accommodation and Food Service Activities",
      "isSelected": "false",
      "dataSubjectCategories":["DS.Employees","DS.Collaborators"],
      "dataTypeCategories":"Personal Data",
      "SubIndustries": [
        {
          "IndustrySector":"Food and Beverage Service Activities",
          "isSelected": "false",
          "dataSubjectCategories":[],
          "dataTypeCategories":[],
          "SubIndustries":[]
        },
        {
          "IndustrySector":"Accommodation",
          "isSelected": "false",
          "dataSubjectCategories":["DS.Minor","DS.Parent","DS.Legal Person","DS.Natural Person","DS.Disable"],
          "dataTypeCategories":[],
          "SubIndustries":[]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

The problem is when I call the service "getBySector" by following code:

```js
this.readjsonService.getBySector(sector).subscribe(response=>{

      if(response.dataSubjectCategories.length>0)
      {
        for(i=0; i<response.dataSubjectCategories.length;i++ ){
          this.DSofSectores.push(response.dataSubjectCategories[i])
        }
      }
      
      })
```

when I see the the typeof the response, it is object!

It tthrows an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataSubjectCategories' of undefined "

it prints the values, though.

Why is it?

what do is that based on the sector,  I get in "response" other data related to it and fill an array of type string which are bind to dropdown list. It works fine, but the following image showes what happens after selecting the sub sector:[image]

PLEASE help me , I am newbie and I am so sick of this :((
Thanks.

EDIT:
when I say

```js
 if (response == undefined) {
          throw new Error("sector not found");
        }
        else { .....
```

it passes the condition, meaning it is not undefined, yet it say "cannot read undefined"

Answer (score 1):

The filter method does not find a match. So the observable is yielding a `undefined`.

```
getBySector(sector): Observable<IIndustrySectors|  undefined> {
     return this.getMainIndustrySectors().pipe(
        map((products: IIndustrySectors[]) => products.find(p => p.IndustrySector === sector)));
                                                     // ^^^ matches none
 }
```

Comment: I am sure that there is at least one to be find. how can i ensure that in the code?

Comment: `if (!response) { throw new Error("sector not found"); }`

Comment: is not it the same as saying if(response)..... , it give this error: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'has-errors: false'.

Answer (score 1):

In your `getBySector` service, you say:

```
products.find(p => p.IndustrySector === sector))
```

Using [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) will return `undefined` if no objects in the array match the selector, in this case if no products have `IndustrySector === sector`.  This is why the service is required to have a return type of `Observable<IIndustrySectors|undefined>`.

If you're seeing this error at compile-time, or as an error in your IDE, it's because of this return type; it knows that the response can be `undefined` and therefore, you have to account for that possibility.  Changing your consuming code to the following should fix the problem:

```
this.readjsonService.getBySector(sector).subscribe(response => {
  if (response !== undefined) {
    if(response.dataSubjectCategories.length > 0) {
      for(let i = 0; i < response.dataSubjectCategories.length; i++) {
        this.DSofSectores.push(response.dataSubjectCategories[i])
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But **be aware** that this means that, at runtime, when a `sector` is passed in that doesn't match any products, the `for` loop **will not be executed**.

Comment: I have done this, now gives me both the "undefined" error and "Expression has changed after it was checked."

Comment: @user3075338 you should `console.log(response)` and see what it is.

Comment: @cgTag it is object. it says [object object]

Comment: try `console.dir(response)`

Comment: @user3075338 try using Chrome. It will inspect the contents of the object in the console.

Comment: @cgTag I am using chrome. the console.dir ==> [object Object]

Comment: @user3075338 That means that somewhere along the lines, the object you're trying to log was converted to a `string`.

Comment: @kevin.groat But it print the results of the "           console.log(response.dataTypeCategories)" , however it says it is undefined!

Comment: @user3075338 That's because you can still access any arbitrary property on a `string`, as with any JavaScript object, but it will be `undefined`

Comment: how can I know what is its type? I have done the "typeof response" and it tells me that it is object.

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataSubjectCategories' of undefined "

As above statement suggest that you are trying to access `dataSubjectCategories` of undefined object. Hence, `response` is not an object.

Use `response[0].dataSubjectCategories` instead of `response.dataSubjectCategories`

**Demo**

```js
var response = [
   {
      "IndustrySector":"Accommodation and Food Service Activities",
      "isSelected": "false",
      "dataSubjectCategories":["DS.Employees","DS.Collaborators"],
      "dataTypeCategories":"Personal Data",
      "SubIndustries": [
        {
          "IndustrySector":"Food and Beverage Service Activities",
          "isSelected": "false",
          "dataSubjectCategories":[],
          "dataTypeCategories":[],
          "SubIndustries":[]
        },
        {
          "IndustrySector":"Accommodation",
          "isSelected": "false",
          "dataSubjectCategories":["DS.Minor","DS.Parent","DS.Legal Person","DS.Natural Person","DS.Disable"],
          "dataTypeCategories":[],
          "SubIndustries":[]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  
 var DSofSectores = [];
if(response[0].dataSubjectCategories.length>0) {
  for(i=0; i<response[0].dataSubjectCategories.length;i++ ) {
    DSofSectores.push(response[0].dataSubjectCategories[i])
  }
}

console.log(DSofSectores);
```